# Generating unique non-random id based on CSV row?

Tags: php, csv, uniqueidentifier

I have a CSV in the format:

```
Bill,Smith,123 Main Street,Smalltown,NY,5551234567
Jane,Smith,123 Main Street,Smalltown,NY,5551234567
John,Doe,85 Main Street,Smalltown,NY,5558901234
John,Doe,100 Foo Street,Bigtown,CA,5556789012
```

In other words, no one field is unique.  Two people can have the same name, two people can have the same phone, etc., but each line is itself unique when you consider all of the fields.

I need to generate a unique ID for each row but it cannot be random.  And I need to be able to take a line of the CSV at some time in the future and figure out what the unique ID was for that person without having to query a database.

What would be the fastest way of doing this in PHP?  I need to do this for millions of rows, so `md5()`'ing the whole string for each row isn't really practical.  Is there a better function I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to be able to later reconstruct the ID from only the text of the line, you *will* need a [hash algorithm](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php). It doesn't have to be MD5, though.

"Millions of IDs" isn't really a problem for modern CPUs (or, especially, GPUs. See Jeff's recent blog about [Speed Hashing](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/speed-hashing.html)), so you might want to do the hashing in a different language than PHP. The only problem I can see is collisions. You need to be certain that your generated hashes really are unique, the chance of which depends on the number of entries, the used algorithm and the length of the hash.

According to Jeff's article, MD5 already is only of the fastest hash algorithms out there (with 10-20,000 million hashes per second), but [NTLM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM) appears to be twice as fast.

Comment: Thanks...may go with CRC32 or md5 after all.

Comment: CRC32 has no guarantee of uniqueness. Some systems (my iPhone) actually calculate SHA-256 faster then MD5.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker Jeff is incorrect when he writes: "Secure hashes are designed to be", we want them to be as fast as possible. This is because they are used for many things such as a file hash as is used in git. When we want to take time we use an iteration  with a function such as PBKDF2. PBKDF2 has a companion function that give a hash function and a duration will return the number of iterations required. On my phone I can hash 40MB/s with SHA-256.

Answer (score 1):

How about just add the unique ID as a field?

```
$csv=file($file);
$i=0;
$csv_new=array();
foreach ($file as $val){
    $csv_new[]=$i.",".$val;
    $i++;
}
```

And output the $csv_new as the new csv file..

Dirty but it may work for you.

Comment: How would you then "be able to take a line of the CSV at some time in the future and figure out what the unique ID was for that person without having to query a database"?

Comment: What Tim said.  I can't modify the CSV...has to be something similar to md5()'ing the whole line, but faster.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
CREATE TABLE data (
    first VARCHAR(50),
    last  VARCHAR(50),
    addr  VARCHAR(50),
    city  VARCHAR(50),
    state VARCHAR(50),
    phone VARCHAR(50),
    id    INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INFILE 'file.csv'
INTO TABLE data
(first,last,addr,city,state,phone);
```

Comment: Because it's not going into a MySQL database, and the ID can't be random anyway.  I need to be able to uniquely identify the record some time in the future without querying a database.

Comment: So what kind of database *are* you using?

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you're saying but I do not see a point. Creating a unique id that auto increments in the database would be the best route. The second route would be creating in the csv something like cell=a1+1 and dragging it down the entire row. In php you ca. Read the file and prepend something such as date(ymd).$id then write it back to the file. Again though this seems silly to do and the database route would be best. Just keep in mind pci compliance and always encrypt the data.
I'll post code later. I'm not at the PC at this time.

It's been a long time, But I found a situation that is sort of like this where I needed to prevent a row being created in a database, I created another column called de_dup which was set to be unique. I then for each row on creation used date('ymd').md5(implode($selected_csv_values)); this would prevent a customer from creating to orders on any given day unless specific information was different ie: firstname,lastname,creditcardnum,billingaddress.